# How to use qmake properly in this case?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have an application in the following directory:

```
\Application
   \GUI
      MainWindow.cpp
      MainWindow.h
      main.cpp
      gui.pro
      gui.pro.user
  \folder1
      file1.cpp
      file1.h
  \folder2
      file2.cpp
      file2.h
```

My application can run in two modes:

> 1. From the console

That version works. I have a makefile which takes care of the dependencies, so I can include my files normally, as they were in the same directory:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

instead of:

```
#include "../folder1/file1.h"
```

> 2. With my GUI

My GUI works without the application - I compile it using the QtCreator.

Now I want to combine my GUI with the application. So I extended the *.pro* file:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\

    Mainwindow.cpp \

    ..\folder1\file1.cpp \

    ..\folder2\file2.cpp \

HEADERS += Mainwindow.h \

    MyTextEdit.h \

   ..\folder1\file1.h \

    ..\folder2\file2.h \
```

However, when I run qmake, I get the following error:

> file1.h: no such file or directory.

I investigated it and it turned out that the compiler expects

```
#include "../folder1/file1.h"
```

instead of:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

Well, I could replace that, but I want to be able to run the console version as well.

How can I fix it? The .pro file isn't a makefile, so I can't use the *INC* variable like I did in the makefile in the console version of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the complete path to the header, because otherwise the compiler does not know where to find the file.

To prevent this, in your GUI's pro-File add the following line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "../folder1/"
```

Also check your header and source paths. There seems to be some missing slashes.

**EDIT**

My complete working gui.pro file using the same folder structure as given above. This way a simple `#include "file1.h"` works in every file of the gui code.

```
TEMPLATE=app
TARGET=gui

QT += widgets

INCLUDEPATH += ../folder1/

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    ../folder1/file1.h \
    ../folder2/file2.h

SOURCES += \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    ../folder1/file1.cpp \
    ../folder2/file2.cpp
```

Comment: It didn't help. I got the same problem.

Comment: Where are your pro files located? Add them to the directory structure in your question.

Comment: See my edit and compare to your pro file. Using exactly the same project structure, this works for me.

Comment: Why didn't you add *INCLUDEPATH += ../folder2/*?

Comment: Because in your example you asked for file1. But it's exactly the same for every other folder, where you use headers from.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. It works for my project:)